# How to style material ui icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to center a material ui icon in a button?

```
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
 <Button><AddIcon style={{ bottom: 3, right: 3 }}/>ADD</Button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWJS4.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a special type of button called *Buttons with icons and label*.

You can read more about it [here](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#buttons-with-icons-and-label).

Answer (score 0):

## To add custom styles to Material ui you need to makeStyles

### Example

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

...

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  },
  label: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
});

...

const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <AddIcon
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        label: classes.label,
      }}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

//using a standard css colour

<BathroomTwoToneIcon style={{ color: "blue" }} />

//import a material ui colour, and use that

import { purple } from "@mui/material/colors";

<BathroomIcon style={{ color: purple[500] }} />